# Experiments with namespace in class protected area

Tags: c++, c++11

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int func();

protected:
    namespace B { enum { D = 0, E = 1 }; }
    namespace C { enum { D = 0, E = 1 }; }
}

int A::func()
{
    int x = A::B::D;
    int y = A::C::E;
    return x + y;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    int x = a.func();
    std::cout << x << std::endl; // 1
    
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

I am just curious and experimenting with `namespace`, because I'd like to have `enums` with same names of values.

I don't want to use `enum class`, because I cannot do operations with integer without overloading operators or casting.

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a namespace inside a class.  Instead, what you can use is a struct like

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int func();

protected:
    struct B { enum { D = 0, E = 1 }; };
    struct C { enum { D = 0, E = 1 }; };
};

int A::func()
{
    int x = A::B::D;
    int y = A::C::E;
    return x + y;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    int x = a.func();
    std::cout << x << std::endl; // 1
    
    return 0;
}
```

which you can see working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0711587bb02ef91e).

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ 14 Standard (7.3.1 Namespace definition)

> 2 Every namespace-definition shall appear in the global scope or in a
> namespace scope

So these namespace definitions within the class scope (where you forgot to place a semicolon)

```
class A
{
public:
    int func();

protected:
    namespace B { enum { D = 0, E = 1 }; }
    namespace C { enum { D = 0, E = 1 }; }
};
^^^
```

are invalid.